# How to compute symbolic theano vector transpose?

Tags: theano

I want to compute the symbolic result of v*v.transpose, with v being a n*1 tensor vector.
However, theano tensor's transpose does not work for vector. And I don't want to use get_value() because I want to do symbolic gradient afterwards.
How should I do in order to get the symbolic transpose?

Comment: it may be confusing about this tensor vector v. It is not a real vector variable, it is just a one-d array, and then I use theano.shared change it into a symbolic variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theano.tensor.transpose` is work with vector. Below is the code to do symbolic v*v.transpose in theano:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

v = T.ivector("v")
b = T.dot(v,T.transpose(v))
z = theano.function([v],b)

A = [1,2,3]
x = z(A)
print x
```